# How can I set a default property for an object that's passed into a constructor?

Tags: javascript, constructor, wrapper, factory, javascript-objects

I'm trying to make a change in one spot to affect the config object passed into all instantiations of an object. The object is made available globally as follows:

```
function Crayons(){
  return {
    foo: ThirdPartyFoo
  }
}
```

The object is initialized in my project with `var myFoo = new Crayons().foo({color: "red"});`

**I'd like to make `{color: "blue"}` the default, so that if someone doesn't pass in a color, blue is set.**

I tried doing

```
function Crayons(){
  var fooWithDefaults = function(){
    this = new ThirdPartyFoo(arguments); //this is invalid
    this.color = "blue"; //and this would overwrite color if it was set
  }

  return {
    foo: fooWithDefaults
  }
}
```

But the `new` keyword is throwing me off, as I don't know how to create a javascript constructor that essentially says `this = new 3rdPartyFoo`.

**What am I missing?**

Comment: `this.color = given || "blue"`

Comment: @AndrewL. that will work for the color, but I still don't know how to construct the object.

Comment: Firstly `Crayons` is not implemented as a true constructor but as a factory instead. Thus, there is no need invoking it with the `new` operator. Secondly `Crayons` does not feature a method `foo`. If invoked it does return an object featuring a property `foo` that does refer to `ThirdPartyFoo` which possibly could be a constructor. Please correct your example to something that is at least valid code or can be run without throwing errors ( I'm referring to `var myFoo = new Crayons.foo({color: "red"});` )

Comment: @PeterSeliger good catch, edited. better?

Comment: Set default value for the argument at the definition of `ThirdPartyFoo` Such as `ThirdPartyFoo(arg = {color: 'blue'}){...code...}`

Comment: Define a constructor with 2 parameters. If one isn't passed it's undefined, then use ||

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either decorate the constructor:

```
function Crayons(){
  function fooWithDefaults() {
    3rdPartyFoo.apply(this, arguments); // this is what you're looking for
    if (!this.color) // or whatever to detect "not set"
      this.color = "blue";
  }
  fooWithDefaults.prototype = 3rdPartyFoo.prototype; // to make `new` work

  return {
    foo: fooWithDefaults
  }
}
```

Or you just make it a factory that returns an instance:

```
function Crayons(){
  function fooWithDefaults(arg) {
    var that = new 3rdPartyFoo(arg); // you should know how many arguments it takes
    if (!that.color) // or whatever to detect "not set"
      that.color = "blue";
    return that;
  }

  return {
    foo: fooWithDefaults
  }
}
```

Here you can also drop the `new` when calling `var myFoo = Crayons.foo({color: "red"});`

An alternative to modifying the instance after its creation would be to decorate the options that are passed in, which is in general the better solution:

```
function Crayons(){
  function fooWithDefaults(arg) {
    if (!arg.color) // or whatever to detect "not set"
      arg.color = "blue";
    return new 3rdPartyFoo(arg);
  }

  return {
    foo: fooWithDefaults
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to "drop the `new`" as I'm trying to avoid refactoring. Your first solution is what I was looking for though. Thanks!

Comment: I meant you *can* drop `new` in the call to `fooWithDefaults`, not that you need to do it. I'd consider the third solution the cleanest one.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function ThirdPartyCrayon(config) {           // constructor :: possible original Crayon implementation

    Object.assign(this, config);
    this.type = "thirdpartycrayon";
}


function createCrayonSetting(defaultConfig) { // factory (creates a closure)

    function CrayonWithDefaults() {           // constructor :: customized Crayon wrapper

        Object.assign(this, defaultConfig);
        ThirdPartyCrayon.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    return {
        Crayon: CrayonWithDefaults
    }
}


var
    setting = createCrayonSetting({color: "blue", strokeWidth: "thin"}),

    crayon1 = new setting.Crayon({color: "red", strokeWidth: "bold"}),
    crayon2 = new setting.Crayon({color: "green"});
    crayon3 = new setting.Crayon();


console.log("crayon1 : ", crayon1);
console.log("crayon2 : ", crayon2);
console.log("crayon3 : ", crayon3);
```